# Alert issue on Google chrome and firefox using javascript

Tags: c#

When an application or a small program is written and opened in chrome/firefox it is showing "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs".

How might I stop this error through a C# program and not through modifying about:config, chromejs, or userchrome.css. I need this to work for each and every user using the application..

Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry... a c# program? You want a locally running program to change browser settings?

Comment: @Mythili : please validate an answer

Comment: @Mythili : please validate an answer

Answer (score 2):

This is Browser Behaviour, I don't think you can change it.

Or create your own dialog box.